# Multiple Choices Questions with choices in 2 or 4 columns for 'examdesign' class

Tags: exam, examdesign

It is necessary for me to write the choices of MCQ in a customized number of columns (say 2 or 4) to efficiently use blank spaces in the paper as well as distribute questions and decrease number of pages as possibl as I can. I see topics which describe how to do this but in different classes like exam class. However, I must use examdesign class because I need to create many forms of the exam by randomizing the rank of questions which is not available in exam class.

This is my code of examdesign class that generates only one column choice:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{examdesign}
\Fullpages
\NoKey 
\def\namedata{Name:}
\class{{ MCQ EXAM}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multiplechoice}      
        \begin{question}
        One column choice
        \choice {choice 1}
        \choice {choice 2}
        \choice[!] {choice 3}
        \choice{choice 4} 
        \end{question}
        \end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

[image: One column choice mode]

I hope to find a way to make the choices like that
[[image: Four column choice mode[2]]

Answer (score 1):

Would that be an acceptable solution?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{examdesign}
\Fullpages
\NoKey 
\def\namedata{Name:}
\class{{ MCQ EXAM}}
\begin{document}
%% examcolumns sets 2 columns in every page of multiplechoice
\begin{multiplechoice}[examcolumns=2]     
\begin{question}
One column choice
\choice {choice 1}
\choice {choice 2}
\choice[!] {choice 3}
\choice{choice 4} 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
One column choice
\choice {choice 1}
\choice {choice 2}
\choice[!] {choice 3}
\choice{choice 4} 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
One column choice
\choice {choice 1}
\choice {choice 2}
\choice[!] {choice 3}
\choice{choice 4} 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
One column choice
\choice {choice 1}
\choice {choice 2}
\choice[!] {choice 3}
\choice{choice 4} 
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. mhtsort for your consideration, this solution seems to be partially acceptable for some cases. Particularly,  I already wrote my exam in two columns.

Comment: I hope to find a radical solution for this problem as in exam class